# Gruntfile.js tasks ERROR

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I'm trying for the first time use Grunt for few tasks. 
In any task I have this error:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

This is my **Gruntfile.js**: http://pastebin.com/SqCEBw0N

This is my **package.json**: http://pastebin.com/5SkxxM44

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing comma on line `104` or `Gruntfile.js`.

You can check syntax of JS without a text editor using [Esprima online](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html).